# How do I evaluate MySQL NOW() field with PHP Date("Y-m-d")?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem evaluating an MySQL NOW() produced field `attend_date` with PHP `Date("Y-m-d")`.

My code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT a.attendeeid, fname, lname, a.groupid, a.memberid, s.attendeeid, suspend
                            FROM attendees AS a
                            JOIN suspended AS s ON a.attendeeid = s.attendeeid 
                            WHERE a.memberid = :memberid
                            AND suspend = "N"
                            AND a.groupid = :groupid
                            ORDER BY lname');
    $stmt->bindValue(':memberid', $_SESSION["memberid"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':groupid', $_POST['groupid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row){ 
        $id = $row[0];
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT historyid, attend_date, attendeeid
                                FROM history
                                WHERE attendeeid = :id
                                ORDER BY historyid
                                DESC LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        foreach($result as $row) {
            if(Date("Y-m-d") != $row['attend_date']){ ... }
```

That last line isn't evaluating at all. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`now()` produces a datetime value, e.g. `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`, which you then compare, AS A STRING, against a date-only value, therefore

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss == yyyy-mm-dd
```

can never ever be equal. Beyond that, why do the filtering in php at all? there's no point in slurping across the entire DB and then throw away some/most/all records in PHP. Do the filtering in MySQL directly:

```
SELECT ... WHERE attend_date = curdate();
```

Comment: Marc B: I can use that. In truth, I forgot about `CURDATE()`. I can use that and make it work. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Try converting the values first

```
if(date("Y-m-d") != date("Y-m-d", strtotime($row['attend_date']))
```

Comment: Thanks Machavity, but that didn't help. In the group I'm selecting (groupid), there are just two attendees. One has yesterday's date for `attend_date`, the other has today's. The one with today's date should be excluded from loading in the Select Box of names, but it loads anyway.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but `attend_date` was set using `NOW()`.